# CodePipeline with CodeBuild error for cross-account ECR login & push for built Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Hey cloud gurus :) I need your help!

I'm trying since quite a while to set up an AWS CodePipeline from source to
build to ECR to ECS for a Docker container where the pipeline is in another
account from where it is deployed. Actually, I have multiple deployment
accounts: Dev, Test and Prod, however, now I just aim to get it deployed into
Dev.

(Also, in my setup I also have ECR repos in all three deployment accounts -
is this the recommended approach compared to maybe one ECR repo in probably the
same account as the pipeline?)

All is using CloudFormation templates, both the AWS infra as well as the pipeline.

#### Problem

I'm currently stuck with a permission issue for CodeBuild pushing to an ECR repo
in another account as CodeBuild and its service role.

#### Overview

The Pipeline account has a pipeline with two stages: source and build taking the
code from CodeCommit and then CodeBuild to build the container. The first stage
works but not the second where the `buildspec.yml` fails logging into the ECR
repo that I have like so:

```
pre_build:
  commands:
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 --registry-ids DEV_ACCOUNT_ID)
```

This fails with the clear and expected error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken
operation: User: arn:aws:sts::PIPELINE_ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/delivery-pipeline-foundation-BuildProjectRole-AAGTGRD1TAPI/AWSCodeBuild-25244ee4-e337-4617-b203-d1687a6a116e
is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

**The CodeBuild project service role does not have permissions to cross-account
access ECR. I know that but not yet how to approach solving it.**

AFAIK, CodePipeline requires a service role in the same account. The build project
service role must also be in the same account and provides permissions
to e.g. CodeBuild, artifacts store and KMS.

I tried to give the CodeBuild project a role in the Dev account but got an error:

```
Failed to call UpdateProject, reason: Invalid service role: Service role account
ID does not match caller's account (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 123458e0-f5d4-4ac9-1060-067e70123249)
```

In summary, the pipeline needs the role in the pipeline account, same for the
CodeBuild project. That all makes sense as those run there and also need access to 
artifacts S3 bucket and related KMS.

**So, how and where to provide the role/permissions to log in to ECR as well as later
to push into a specific repo so that the docker commands can be in the `buildspec.yml`
file?**

I'm planning to use CodeDeploy ECS to deploy once I have the build stage working.

**Is the overall approach recommended for cross-account deployments and/or are
there other approaches you use?**

Most examples online are much [simpler with a single account](https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-continuous-deployment)
with [this related issue](https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-continuous-deployment/issues/46)
or just [general cross-account without ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) (which I have working).

Thanks in advance for your help on this one!

Comment: I "solved" it in 2 ways: 1. Assuming cross accounts role in the codebuild cli (build script) with `aws sts assume-role`. 2. I've used `CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction` which allows to do your 2nd scenario. Meaning passing cross account role to the resource and in the build spec passing role from cross account with required permissions to deploy cloudformation. But the 2nd approach does not work for codebuild. My thinking is that codebuild actually deploys a codebuild resource on cross account, but cloudformation only invokes it with assume role at deployment time. Do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user in the other account which holds ECR repo and give its Access Key and Secret Key as Environment Variables to your CodeBuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

Add AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser to your build role.
If you have permission boundary set to your build role( Codestar by-default creates the permission boundary), you have to update that also.Added this at the end of permission boundary content.
`{ "Sid": "7", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken", "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability", "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer", "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy", "ecr:DescribeRepositories", "ecr:ListImages", "ecr:DescribeImages", "ecr:BatchGetImage", "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy", "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview", "ecr:ListTagsForResource", "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings", "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload", "ecr:UploadLayerPart", "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload", "ecr:PutImage" ], "Resource": [ "*" ] }`